# LISP - get all method names from a class

Tags: methods, lisp, common-lisp, clos

Can I get in LISP all the method names from a class?

Actually I need the methods, which have

> set-

in their names.

Comment: What you are looking for is called MOP - [MetaObject Protocol](http://mop.lisp.se/).

Comment: Methods are not defined on classes. They specialize generic function according to one or more arguments. You may want to find all methods named "set-" which specializes on the class as the first argument. But perhaps more importantly, why?

Comment: @coredump using SET I am setting some properties and I need to print those properties names. Some of them are saved in slots, but there are properties which are not saved in slots, so getting all the slots is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

For LispWorks:

```
(defun find-all-methods (class prefix)
  (loop for method in (clos:specializer-direct-methods class)
        for gf           = (method-generic-function method)
        for fname        = (generic-function-name gf)
        for fname-string = (when (symbolp fname) (symbol-name fname))
        when (and (stringp fname-string)
                  (>= (length fname-string)
                      (length prefix))
                  (string= fname-string prefix
                           :end1 (length prefix)
                           :end2 (length prefix)))
        collect method))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 20 > (pprint (find-all-methods (find-class 'capi:button) "PRINT-"))

(#<STANDARD-METHOD CAPI:PRINT-COLLECTION-ITEM NIL (CAPI:BUTTON T) 40E06173D3>
 #<STANDARD-METHOD CAPI:PRINT-CAPI-BUTTON NIL (CAPI:BUTTON) 40E05F9DDB>)
```

Comment: This also works on SBCL using `(ql:quickload 'closer-mop)` and adjusting the missing functions to the ones from the `closer-mop` package.